# Tkinter checkbox split list

Tags: python, list, checkbox, tkinter, split

I'm trying to split a list from a file with ~ 100 items to several lines of checkboxes (10 per line ~). Because all items are on the same long line.

I tried to split the first file into nFiles with 10 items max and create new lines of checkbutton in the frame. 
But no way, i got only all items in the same line:

```
class DisplayApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("My Menu")
        frame_1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Frame 1")
        frame_1.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        path = '/home/lst/*.txt'
        files=glob.glob(path)
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
                for item in lst_file:
                    tk.Checkbutton(frame_1, text=item.rstrip()).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DisplayApp().mainloop()
```

Initiale txt file:

```
item1 
item2
item3
...
item100
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a counter and `grid` geometry manager will make your life much easier. You can see how the `count` variable dictates the row and the column where a `Checkbutton` will go in the frame. Have a look at the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import glob

class DisplayApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("My Menu")
        frame_1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Frame 1")
        frame_1.grid(row=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        path = '/path/to/your/txt/files'
        files=glob.glob(path)
        count = 0
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
                for item in lst_file:
                    tk.Checkbutton(frame_1, text=item.rstrip()).grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
                    count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DisplayApp().mainloop()
```

I had a file with 30 items. It will work with any number of files. Give it a try.

[image]

Comment: @Indi59 Glad I could help.